# Creating a matlab function that list books

Tags: matlab

i created a function:

```
function display_book(x)
[a,b] = strtok(x,',') ;
[b,c] =strtok(b,',');
b=strrep(b,',',' ');
c=strrep(c,',',' ');
fprintf('Title  : %s \n',a);
fprintf('Author :%s \n',b);
fprintf('Number of pages :%s \n',c);
end
```

It basically shows the title author and number of pages of a user string input seperated by a delimeter. 
Eg:

```
 display_book('MATLAB 101, ATTAWAY CALMS, 115')
 Title: MATLAB 101
 Author: ATTAWAY CALMS
 Number of Pages: 115
```

I followed up with a diffrent code where i call the display_book function:

```
 function library

 x=input(' What would you like to do : ','s');

 while strcmpi('quit',x) ~= 1

 Q=input(' Please  create a book with a title, author and number of pages: 
 ','s');
 display_book(Q);

 fprintf('The %s has been added to your library \n',Q);

 x=input(' \n What would you like to do: ','s');

 if strcmpi('list books',x) == 1
 end

 end

 disp('Good-Bye')
 end
```

So what i have so far is when i call my library function it allows me to display books until i enter quit to stop the code.

However, i want to improve on the code and be able to list the books that i have entered. If i had two books entered before quitting my library, i want to be able to see what books i have entered.

example:

```
list_books

What would you like to do: list books
Title: The Hobbit
Author: J. R. R. Tolkien
Number of Pages: 454

Title: Harry Potter and the Cursed Child
Author: J. K. Rowling
Number of Pages: 245
```

I need some help to figure out how i can 'store'  the inputs into my library function.

Comment: How about not just displaying stuff through `fprintf` but actually assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the title,author,# of pages in a cell array, then access its members when neccessary:

```
function myScript() %this will create an empty cell array, push some books and list them
    myLibrary={};
    myLibrary=save_book('MATLAB 101, ATTAWAY CALMS,115',myLibrary);
    myLibrary=save_book('some bad book, me,123',myLibrary);
    list_books(myLibrary);
end

function [lib]=save_book(x,lib) %saves a book to library
[a,b] = strtok(x,',') ;
[b,c] =strtok(b,',');
b=strrep(b,',',' ');
c=strrep(c,',',' ');
lib=[lib; {a,b,c}];
end

function list_books(library) %lists books in library
    for i=1:1:size(library,1)
        fprintf('Title  : %s \n',library{i,1});
        fprintf('Author :%s \n',library{i,2});
        fprintf('Number of pages :%s \n\n',library{i,3});
    end
end
```